# number.toLocaleString() displays currency symbol for some languages, code for other

Tags: javascript

I'm using a number.toLocaleString() function, my problem is that, for some currencies, it outputs the price with a currency symbol, in other it outputs the currency codes.

Some of the currencies don't have a symbol, but all have a code. I want to normalize this and display the code for all currencies.

Current code:

```
  const convertedPrice = Math.round(convertPrice(price, currency) * 10) / 10;
  const formattedPrice = convertedPrice.toLocaleString(country, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: currency
  });
```

Current output if country US, currency USD: `$1.00`
Expected output: `USD 1.00`

Current and expected output if country CZ, currency CZK: `CZK 26.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `currencyDisplay: 'code'`.

```
const formattedPrice = convertedPrice.toLocaleString(country, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "currency",
    currencyDisplay: "code"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "currency Display" as an option and set it to "code".

currencyDisplay:"code"